# Reworded question, reopen without waiting for reopen votes?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388149/determining-the-best-ways-of-adding-unit-tests-to-a-large-project-that-makes-g

I've reworded my question to fit the guidelines, so how can this be re-opened without waiting for 4 more reopen votes?

Comment: ... what do you mean reopen without getting enough votes to reopen? that doesn't make sense. And, it's still very much primarily opinion based.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be reopened...

Comment: I second Tunaki's point.  You've done nothing to address the reason your question was closed.  Some minor re-wording hasn't changed the core question, which was the problem.

Comment: That's lame. It's a very valid question and I would like input on the best ways - ways, not way, since there are many ways in programming to approach a problem.

Comment: @DerreckDean No, it's *not* a valid question (on SO anyway).  Until you realize that you won't be able to fix it to be an on-topic question.

Comment: Can it be moved to a different section? (out of SO into Programming or somewhere)

Comment: Then what are my options? Can this be moved from SO to Programming? The comments here just state that it's not a valid question but there's nothing said of what can be done to either fix the question or move it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: @DerreckDean I honestly don't see how the question could be made into an appropriate question.  It's honestly an opinion poll at its heart, and even that aside, it's also *way* too broad.  I don't really see it being fixable.

Comment: So is there a place in the StackExchange network that this question would be appropriate? Because I would like to post it. I really don't know how to reword it in a way that fits the SO way, since the way I worded it is what I want. Different ways of attacking the problem, since I have a large codebase and can't attack every test with a hammer, so to speak. So far it seems like a lot of 'this question is invalid' and not a lot of 'here are ways to fix this'.

Comment: @DerreckDean best suggestion is to go to [Software Engineering Meta](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (formally known as Programmers) and ask if the question is on topic there.  I do not know the scope of the site well enough to tell you if it is acceptable or not, but I strongly suspect that it isn't for the same reasons previously mentioned about SO (very opinionated, very broad).  Unfortunately not every programming question under the sun has a place on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DerreckDean Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general, does not "owe you" a place in which to ask a question.

Comment: The hardware store doesn't teach cooking classes; Saturday night at the pub isn't a good place to study; you can't take a shower on the city bus. In the same way, SE isn't the right place for some questions, as good and valid as they may be to ask.

Comment: And that's fine. I get that SE doesn't owe me anything, but the level of trolling that SO and meta has allowed in recent years is terrible.  This is what I want to know. Is there a place, like Programmers, Code Review, etc., where this is a valid question and won't get closed? That's all I want to know. I don't care if *you* as a person don't care for/don't like my question, but I'm sure there are other people out there with constructive thoughts on the problem I pose.

Comment: I think psubsee2003's suggestion above of checking out [SoftwareEngineering.SE] is the best available; if your question doesn't fit there, I can't think of any other site on SE where it would. The Meta.SE post [Which computer science programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598) provides a good overview of the related sites on the network.

Comment: @DerreckDean: "*Sounds like a lot of troll mods with no power in their lives.*" Pro-tip: claiming that people who disagree with you are trolls who do so only as a salve for their own personal problems is *not* an effective way to get people to agree with your take on things.

Comment: @DerreckDean: "*I'm sure there are other people out there with constructive thoughts on the problem I pose.*" I'm sure there are as well. That doesn't mean we want it here. This site is not for any old question that might be useful. It's for specific, focused questions, which yours is not. This is not a *discussion* site.

Answer (score 22):

You don't.  You wait for 4 more reopen votes (assuming others feel it merits reopening at all).

Comment: Can it be closed again if it's been re-opened?

Comment: @DerreckDean Yes it can

Comment: So how do I get my question answered without the topic being closed?

Comment: @DerreckDean You ask an appropriate question that doesn't actually merit closure.

Answer (score 3):

It is unfortunate that the question still seems very opinion based.

You will inevitably get opinions in answers, but better answers will be backed up by demonstrable facts. In asking your question, you need to directly attempt to get those facts.

Change your "should I do A or B" to "How do I do X" in such a way that demonstrates that you've done your homework, while reducing the ancillary information (the parts that make your question less applicable to others).

As your question is currently written, I am not willing to vote to reopen.

Comment: Doing this would just make the question too broad; it'd still merit closure.

Comment: Yes, it would need to survive the rest of the close reason gauntlet - which means to address the breadth issue, would probably mean it needs to be whittled down further.

Comment: So it's rather disingenuous to suggest that they make that change, given that you're creating a whole new problem when fixing the current one.

Comment: Perhaps the point is moot - he cross posted it to SE.SE, where it is now getting a positive reception.

Comment: So rather than asking on their meta to determine if it is on-topic as I suggested, he just asked..... sounds like a q-ban waiting to happen